# Queries @media para sites 100% responsivo?

Tags: html, css

Atualmente trabalho com três queries sempre baseando na largura mínima e largura máxima da tela. A Mobile define de 250px a 480px, a Tablet coloquei como 481px a 1023px e a de Desktop coloquei a partir de 1024px.

Atualmente nos aparelhos que testei estão funcionando com apenas bugs pequenos que não atrapalham o uso porém amigos e desenvolvedores teem relatados problemas de quando a responsavidade do site. O site é o seguinte:

http://webt.pe.hu/bluc/index.html

esse é um domínio de teste, e deixo uma NOTA, tenho apenas a página Cortana pronta, então cliquem no circulo cortana a para ver o corpo do site.

A grande duvida está sendo na declaração dessas queries, tenho que declarar ela baseando tambem na altura? Qual é a melhor maneira de declarar as mesmas? E em html, posso usar alguma meta para ajudar nisso?

EDIT

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Telas Pequenas */
@media (min-width: 249px) and (max-width: 480px) 
{

}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Telas Médias */
@media (min-width: 481px)  and (max-width: 1024px) 
{

}

/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Telas Grandes */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) 
{

}

/* Geral */
```

Comment: Por favor informe qual o problema que está tendo: comportamento desejado e comportamento atual, e se possível os trechos de código relevantes. Do contrário, teríamos que sair fuçando à procura de problemas, sem saber direito o que procurar (a menos que o problema fosse óbvio, é claro). P.S. O link está correto? Aqui está dando 404.

Comment: Consertei o link.. Realmente não descrevi erro porque eu não sei qual é o erro, testei em dois desktop totalmente diferentes, um wide screen e outro monitor quadrado e em ambos funcionou perfeitamente, o mesmo aconteceu com um tablet, e 3 smartphones de resoluções diferentes. Porém alguns amigos e desenvolvedores que pedi para acessar tiveram problemas de visualização.

Comment: Logo imagino que o problema são nos queries media que estou usando, dei detalhes dela no tópico e para ver elas em ação é so entrar no link, dar um ctrl+U e abrir qualquer um arquivo de estilo, com exceção do bootstrap, hover e font, que são frameworks.

Comment: Apenas queria saber qual as queries mais adequadas para um site responsivo e se ha algum meta que ajude nisso, deixei o link do site apenas para ver se achem bugs e tambem tenham acesso total ao código.

Comment: Não é viável olhar seu site inteiro atrás de erros. Olhe [esta foto](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oym2o.jpg) de como o mesmo fica em meu monitor. No arquivo que vi, `index.css`, você não trata resoluções acima de 1024. E é exatamente nesta que meu monitor se encaixa. Caso queira uma resposta mais completa, a noite terei tempo para ajudar melhor

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho Esses seus amigos disseram qual Sistema Operacional e browser eles estão usando? Eu não reparei nada de incomum ou que pudesse ser melhorado nos poucos css que eu vi (só abri alguns, não olhei todos), mas eu notei que a disposição dos elementos varia com a altura da janela (Win7, Chrome: http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9MPJ.jpg). É seu objetivo que a tela não role? Se for, sua pergunta sobre "declarar baseado também na altura" *provavelmente* teria como resposta "sim" (só que eu não tenho experiência com esse tipo de tela pra opinar).

Comment: Achei o erro mesmo, é que eu defini essa pagina fiz porem não defini queries para altura, vou ver o que eu faço, se crio outra sem ser fixa ou não.. Ao clicar na bolinha Cortana o site funciona normal ne?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, você deve prestar atenção em alguns pontos.

Você está trabalhando com bootstrap. Não sei se você conhece, mas bootstrap é uma ferramenta extremamente poderosa, tanto em `css` como em `javascript`, possuindo diversos `plugins` pré-prontos que facilitariam muito sua vida desenvolvendo (especialmente se você não é um usuário avançado), além de ter um sistema de `grid` excelente voltado para sites responsivos.

Recomendo fortemente que você estude mais o bootstrap para fazer esse tipo de website.

Mas, caso você deseje fazer o desenvolvimento bruto, aqui vão algumas considerações.

Você deve definir um objetivo principal para o desenvolvimento do seu `css`, como:

- O meu site deve rodar principalmente em celulares e tablets?
- O meu site deve rodar mais em notebooks e desktops?
- Quem é o meu usuário? De onde ele está acessando meu site?

A partir dai você consegue definir se irá desenvolver ele em `Mobile First` (voltado para mobile como prioridade) ou se irá desenvolver de modo padrão, efetuando os ajustes conforme for diminuindo as telas - se necessário.

A grande questão aqui é o fluxo de desenvolvimento, e não as `@media` que você deve usar. Se o seu desenvolvimento for com foco em `Mobile First`, comece o seu código `css` voltado para celulares e tablets e somente mude o layout quando for preciso passar para uma tela maior. Por exemplo, se você deseja uma lista de notícias com 1 coluna no celular e 3 colunas no computador, você deve utilizar um `css` mais ou menos assim:

```
.coluna {
   display:inline-block;
   width:100%;
   background:#fff;
   border-radius:3px;
   border:1px solid #eee;
}
@media(min-width:1024px) {
    .coluna {
        width:33%;
    }
}
```

Deste modo, a coluna terá a mesma aparência em todas as resoluções, com exceção da largura, que irá mudar de 100% para 33% quando atingir uma resolução maior que de um tablet(neste exemplo, 1024px). As demais definições irão se repetir, a não ser que você sobrescreva o `css` dentro do `@media(min-width:1024px)`.

A partir do momento que você define o código dentro de um `min-width` e `max-width` ele ficará restrito àquele intervalo somente, ou seja, as propriedades não serão passadas adiante.

Comment: Excelente ponto sobre o bootstrap, de fato incluir o bootstrap numa página e não usar o sistema de grid é um baita desperdício do potencial dessa plataforma. Com grids a gente trabalha mais com classes prontas do que [diretamente] com *media queries*. Sugiro ao AP que leia um pouco sobre o assunto, aqui por exemplo tem [uma introdução ao sistema de grid](http://webdevacademy.com.br/tutoriais/ux/bootstrap-3-layouts-sistema-grids/).

Comment: Bom, eu não sabia da grid vou dar uma estudada na mesma, sobre os medias para mim está certo, o controle de largura está correto só não consigo fazer o controle da altura.

Comment: Eu diria que na maioria dos casos é inútil você fazer o controle de altura, já que ele não tem um impacto tão grande na exibição do layout. Neste caso vale mais a pena manter o foco na orientação, se é portrait ou landscape, pois em alguns casos pode mudar o @media mesmo sendo o mesmo aparelho.

Comment: Realmente também acho isso kk, porém dei bobeira de tentar fazer uma página fixa como index se reparar essa página http://webt.pe.hu/bluc/pg/cortana.html ela custa apresentar problemas, só em resoluções que praticamente não existem.. agora a página inicial que fiz fixa apresenta problemas na altura por causa do slide

Comment: Sim. Mas dê uma lida no link do amigo @mgibsonbr e também procure por mais materiais sobre o bootstrap. Eu comecei usando ele e hoje eu tenho um arquivo que uso em TODOS os meus projetos, onde peguei somente o grid, fiz algumas pequenas adaptações para o meu fluxo de trabalho e utilizo em tudo que faço. É excelente!

Comment: Dei uma olhada no link, gostei do que vi, vai dar uma brincada com isso, porém acho melhor fazer a estilização com as queries mesmo, para ter mais controle do que será apresentado e ter mais personalização, o meu erro nesse site foi tentar fazer o index com posições fixas para tudo.. Mas vou dar uma investigada nesse método

Comment: Sim, se o seu site for responsive, não tem como fugir do uso de `@media`, a não ser que você crie um arquivo .css para cada tamanho, exemplo 498.css 768.css, 1024.css e faça o load do arquivo de modo dinâmico com js (exemplo). Mas seria horrível, pois teria que declarar TODAS as propriedades css em cada arquivo. E se mudar em um, deverá mudar em todos. Faça o layout css voltado para mobile e modifique apenas o necessário de modo crescente( 468px -> 768px -> 1024px).